# Failed to build iOS app (Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000), Flutter 0.5.1)

Tags: xcode, dart, flutter

It is a test-drive example "https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/#terminal"
I have got the following error, please comment how to resolve this issue.

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-gmodules'
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-fbuild-session-file=/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation'
    clang-3.5: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ctvpprsqskddfxbtqtsepwpaebqm/Index/DataStore'
    clang-3.5: error: option '-fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session' requires '-fbuild-session-timestamp=<seconds since Epoch>'
    Command /usr/local/bin/clang-omp failed with exit code 1
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-gmodules'
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-fbuild-session-file=/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation'
    clang-3.5: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ctvpprsqskddfxbtqtsepwpaebqm/Index/DataStore'
    clang-3.5: error: option '-fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session' requires '-fbuild-session-timestamp=<seconds since Epoch>'
    Command /usr/local/bin/clang-omp failed with exit code 1
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    error: the following command failed with exit code 1 but produced no further output
    CompileC /Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ctvpprsqskddfxbtqtsepwpaebqm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_vers.o /Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ctvpprsqskddfxbtqtsepwpaebqm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources/Runner_vers.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-gmodules'
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-fbuild-session-file=/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation'
    clang-3.5: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ctvpprsqskddfxbtqtsepwpaebqm/Index/DataStore'
    clang-3.5: error: option '-fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session' requires '-fbuild-session-timestamp=<seconds since Epoch>'
    Command /usr/local/bin/clang-omp failed with exit code 1
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-gmodules'
    clang-3.5: error: unknown argument: '-fbuild-session-file=/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation'
    clang-3.5: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/nelson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ctvpprsqskddfxbtqtsepwpaebqm/Index/DataStore'
    clang-3.5: error: option '-fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session' requires '-fbuild-session-timestamp=<seconds since Epoch>'
    Command /usr/local/bin/clang-omp failed with exit code 1
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 7 Plus.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue as the following:

If you look at the question carefully, it triggered an outdated version of clang 3.5, I uninstalled an outdated version and installed a new one.

1. remove clang-omp from os x

   ```
   $ brew uninstall clang-omp
   ```
2. After uninstall clang-omp, flutter installer required to update to the latest version. Actually, I did the update before but I did it again.

   ```
   $ flutter upgrade
   ```
3. I try to run flutter again but it cannot be compiled. It was missing clang-omp

   ```
   $ flutter run    
   === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
       error: can't exec '/usr/local/bin/clang-omp' (No such file or directory)
       Command /usr/local/bin/clang-omp failed with exit code 71
       error: can't exec '/usr/local/bin/clang-omp' (No such file or directory)
       Command /usr/local/bin/clang-omp failed with exit code 71
   ```
4. Because it required an updated version of clang during compilation. I installed llvm

   ```
   $ brew install llvm
   ```
5. and update the PATH accordingly.

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
6. Compile the application again, it was compiled successfully.

   ```
   $ flutter run
   Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 7 Plus in debug mode...
   Starting Xcode build...                                          
   ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                    1.1s
   └─Compiling, linking and signing...                  8.6s
   Xcode build done.                                           11.3s
   Syncing files to device iPhone 7 Plus...                     3.9s

     To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
   An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone 7 Plus is available at: http://127.0.0.1:8100/
   For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".

   Initializing hot reload...                                       
   Reloaded 0 of 391 libraries in 486ms.
   ```